# Why do multiple JUnit TestWatchers not spawn multiple test method calls?

Tags: java, junit

I'm using multiple JUnit TestWatchers on each of the tests in my test suite. I was worried that each TestWatcher was calling `base.evaluate()` and each test was actually being run multiple times (once by each call to `base.evaluate()`). That does not seem to be happening, **which is great**, but I'm confused as to why that is the case.

**Why don't multiple JUnit TestWatchers in a single test result in multiple calls to the test method?**

I think I have some fundamental misunderstanding of how these components (in particular `base.evaluate()`) interact, but haven't found any good explanations that have resolved this confusion on my part.

```
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher;
import org.junit.runner.Description;
import org.junit.runners.model.Statement;

public class SimpleTest {

    @Rule
    public TestWatcher testWatcher1 = new TestWatcher() {
        @Override
        public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {
            return new Statement() {
                public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("testWatcher1");
                        base.evaluate();
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    };

    @Rule
    public TestWatcher testWatcher2 = new TestWatcher() {
        @Override
        public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {
            return new Statement() {
                public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("testWatcher2");
                        base.evaluate();
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    };


    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
testWatcher2
testWatcher1
test

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Upon further investigation:**
Adding `System.out.println(base.toString());` inside of each of those `evaluate()` calls lead to some really interesting output:

```
testWatcher2
com.glenpierce.Tests.base.SimpleTest$1$1@3c09711b
testWatcher1
org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod@5cc7c2a6
test

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It seems like each TestWatcher is looking at a different scope. Am I unintentionally nesting these things?

Answer (score 0):

Rules in JUnit are designed so that they are linked to each other. `base.evaluate()` in one rule causes the next rule to run, until all the rules have run. Only if all the rules calls `base.evaluate()` then the test method is run.